# How to use autocomplete extender multiple times in single textbox?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

I am working on an real estate based application in ASP.NET . Here, I want to 
use autocomplete extender to get cities. I have  tried the  following

Below is the design section where I have used a `TextBox` named "txtCity" along with an autocomplete extender whose target control is the "txtCity" and 
web service method is "GetCities".

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajax" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
    <title>Ajax AutoCompleteExtender without Webservice</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
      <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <ajax:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" 
              TargetControlID="txtCity" MinimumPrefixLength="1" EnableCaching="true" 
              CompletionSetCount="1" CompletionInterval="1000" ServiceMethod="GetCities" >
        </ajax:AutoCompleteExtender>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Below is the Webservice Method which will return names of cities in the form of a list.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;


[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetCities(string prefixText)
{
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection  
  (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ToString());
  con.Open();
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from City where CityName  
  like @Name+'%'", con);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", prefixText);
  SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  da.Fill(dt);
  List<string> CoityNames = new List<string>();
  for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
     CityNames.Add(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
  }
  return CityNames;

}
```

Here, when I enter any character all cities matching that character gets displayed in a drop-down manner and after selecting any city, the selected city is displayed in the textbox.

When I search for another city then the new city appears in the textbox while the previously selected city gets deleted. But I don't want the previously selected cities to disappear.

I want to use functionality used in sites like 99acres.com.

Comment: You can use Jquery plugins to achieve this. http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-jQuery-UI-Plugin-For-Simle-Tokenized-Autocomplete-Autocomplete-Multiselect.html

Comment: I don't think there is any way to customize these server controls. These controls are good as long as you use the functionaty provided by them. Jquery controls gives you the possibility of costomization  as per your needs. That is way there are so many jquery controls are available and if not available you can easily build your own.

Comment: I have formatted the code better by making appropriate indentations (as it improves readability) and also removed the extra indentation from the text between your design and web-service code because otherwise it gets hidden within the code block. I have also reworded the sentences to better explain your problem.

Comment: Please don't use code block formatting (indenting by 4 characters) for normal text. If you want to highlight some text then use the text formatting options like bold, italics etc. Also, language names are generally not required in title because they are part of tags.

Answer (score 0):

The exact functionality is is being demonstrated using RAD controls here http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/autocompletebox/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx

You just need to set SQL Data Source and bit of AJAX wrapping.

Screenshot:
[image]